# How to prepare http buffer using curl

Tags: c++, c, json, curl, libcurl

I wanted to `send/recv` the http packet in non-blocking mode using curl. So I need to prepare the buffer by using curl. Once the buffer prepared I can send that buffer using `curl_easy_send()` API.I don't want to use `curl_easy_perform/curl_multi_perform()` API to avoid blocking operation.

Is there any API/procedure to prepare the http buffer and give it to the application by using curl?

Comment: Based on [this libcurl example code](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/sendrecv.html), it is recommended NOT to use `curl_easy_send()` or `curl_easy_recv()` to implement HTTP.

Comment: @SSC How can we send / recv in non-blocking mode ?

Comment: Is there any way to get the sending buffer before transfer to server using curl ?

Answer (score 0):

First, curl_multi_perform() is not blocking.

Secondly, libcurl does not expose such internals that you ask for. You really shouldn't need that anyway.

Third: as mentioned in comments already: we **strongly** advice against implementing HTTP(S) using curl_easy_recv / curl_easy_send. Not only because the existing API already does it for you and is battle proven, but also because it is a hell of a lot of work to get it done right.